# AddThis Wordpress plugin not working with AJAX theme

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, plugins, addthis

I'm using the AddThis Wordpress plugin to include share buttons underneath each post in an AJAX theme, and am having trouble getting the code right.

I inserted the following code in the custom button field on the settings page:

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style" id="toolbox">
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
</div>
```

Then in the post loop in the main page PHP file I have this:

```
<script>
    var tbx = document.getElementById("toolbox"),
    svcs = {email: 'Email', print: 'Print', facebook: 'Facebook', expanded: 'More'};

    for (var s in svcs) {
        tbx.innerHTML += '<a class="addthis_button_'+s+'">'+svcs[s]+'</a>';
    });

    function ReinitializeAddThis() {
        if (window.addthis) {
            window.addthis.toolbox("#toolbox");
        }
    }
</script>
<iframe style="display: none;" onload="ReinitializeAddThis();"></iframe>
```

The buttons will only load sporadically, and disappear after a refresh. I'm also getting the error *Uncaught ReferenceError: ReinitializeAddThis is not defined* which is confusing... I'd really appreciate any insight and I apologize if anything is unclear. Thanks!

Comment: `<iframe style="display: none;" onload="ReinitializeAddThis();"></iframe>` - what is this?

Comment: @dalbaeb It's part of the code I took from this thread (http://bit.ly/18kLKoQ) on activating AddThis after an AJAX load. My understanding is that it's supposed to execute the `ReinitializeAddThis();` function. (edited link, having trouble with the markdown)

Comment: Are you loading the button via AJAX? If not then research for a cleaner way of including it in the page and your problem will go away.

Comment: I am not loading via AJAX. This is the solution I came across while researching the use of the plugin in AJAX themes. The solution worked for other users but is not working properly for me, which is why I posed the question here. Thanks!

Comment: Well, this solution is for "loading ... AddThis toolbox, into a page via AJAX", which seems to be not your case. Have you tried a standard way of including the AddThis button? If not try it.

Answer (score 0):

I have arrived at a solution, so I'll post it here in case anyone ever runs into the same problem.

On the AddThis settings page, I pasted this code into the "custom button" field:

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style" id="toolbox">
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
</div>
```

Then in the post loop within the main page PHP file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
            console.log("All AJAX requests completed");

            if (window.addthis) {
                window.addthis.toolbox(".addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style");
                console.log("AddThis rendered")

            };
        });
        var tbx = document.getElementById("toolbox"),
            svcs = {email: 'Email', print: 'Print', facebook: 'Facebook', expanded: 'More'};

        for (var s in svcs) {
            tbx.innerHTML += '<a class="addthis_button_'+s+'">'+svcs[s]+'</a>';
        };
    </script>
```

This calls the `window.addthis.toolbox()` function for each individual post and creates a sharing toolbox after AJAX has rendered as specified [on this page](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381263-addthis-client-api#rendering-js).